# Building a complex regex with "conditions"

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to build a complex regex with the following constraints:

**1. My string can only be composed of:**

```
    "Regular" alphanumeric characters : a-zA-Z0-9

    4 specials characters : space . _ -
```

**2. Length has to be between 3 and 25**

So far it's quite easy but then it gets complicated :

**3. There cannot be 2 consecutive special characters, unless the 1st one is a space and the 2nd one isn't a space. *Logical consequence : there cannot be 3 consecutive special characters***

**4 The string cannot start or end with a space**

I'm especially struggling with 3.
Any help/hint would be much appreciated.

Examples:

```
" lkjsdi1SD" => FALSE (starts with a space)
"-lkjsdi1SD" => TRUE
"lkjsd -i1SD " => FALSE (ends with a space)
".Dg5 -lkjsdi1SD" => TRUE
"jhv5675gjjvghHJHvg655775vfFVHFJFf445576JHFFfhd12" => FALSE (too long)
"jhv  12" => FALSE (two consecutive spaces)
"as" => FALSE (too short)
"a r" => TRUE
```

Comment: What does your pattern look like now? So, `[-_.]` can be at the string start/end? Please share your test cases.

Comment: Case 3 and 4 are contradictory

Comment: Try `^(?=.{3,25}$)\b[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?:(?:[._-]| [._-]*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)*\b$` but without test cases, it is a "don't-work" ping-pong game.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
so far I have this ugly
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-][a-zA-Z0-9_ .-]{1,23}[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]$/', $var)

that does not meet the 3rd requirement, is ugly and incorporate the space directly which is also ugly ( I could use \s but I don't want all the whitespaces, just the space)

Comment: @Thamilan no they are not

Comment: I see, but the point is: can the `.`, `_` and `-` be at the end of the string? If yes, try [`^(?=.{3,25}$)(?:[._-]*\b)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?:(?:[._-]| [._-]*)[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+)*(?:\b[._-]*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/xY1yZ2/2).

Comment: Just a quick shot: https://regex101.com/r/cP7kS9/2

Comment: There is no way to help you without a complete set of test cases.

Comment: Try [`^(?=.{3,25}$)[._-]*\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:[._-]| [._-]*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b[._-]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/xY1yZ2/4). It passes all your test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, ........wed passes and it shouldn't

Comment: So, update your test cases! Try [`^(?=.{3,25}$)[._-]?\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:[._-]| [._-]*)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b[._-]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xY1yZ2/5).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew fails again, "-f --j 0 -o" passes and it shouldn't. Instead of giving me regex with no explanations how about elaborating a constructive answer so it can benefit my understanding and also people that will have the same case as me later on :) ? About my examples it is just illustrations it cannot describe all the cases that won't fit. However, my 5 requirements describe all the cases.

Comment: Before I post, I must be sure I am posting something useful. Try [`^(?=.{3,25}$)[._-]?\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(?:[._-]| [._-]?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\b[._-]?$`](https://regex101.com/r/xY1yZ2/7). I think the only issue was now with the `*` that matches 0+ occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using:

```
^                       # Start of string
 (?=.{3,25}$)           # The total string length is from 3 to 25
 [._-]?                 # An optional . _ or - (? means "match 1 or 0 times")
 [a-zA-Z0-9]+           # one or more alphanumeric symbols
 (?:                    # Zero or more sequences of:
    (?:[._-]|[ ][._-]?)   # one . _ or - OR a space followed with an optional . _ or -
    [a-zA-Z0-9]+          # one or more alphanumerics
 )*                     # (here * defines zero or more times)
 [._-]?                 # one optional . _ or -  
$                       # End of string
```

See the inline description for each part (I used `/x` VERBOSE (or free-space) modifier to enable comments that is helpful to keep long patterns readable).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY1yZ2/9)

**More pattern details**

- `^` - start of string [**anchor**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), the regex engine will only look for the whole pattern at the string start. Thus, if there is a space at the start, no match will be returned as `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, the first obligatory subpattern, requires an alphanumeric, and `[._-]?` (a [**character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that matches one or zero  `.`, `_`, or `-` (the [**`?`** is a **quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) matching one or zero occurrences of the quantified subpattern) only allows 1 of these 3 characters before the first alphanumeric.
- `(?=.{3,25}$)` is a [**positive lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) anchored at the start, that requires at least 3 and at most 25 characters other than a newline (`.` matches any char other than a LF if `/s` modifier is not defined) from start till end (`$` is the string end anchor that matches at the end of string or before the final char that is a newline character, replace with `\z` if you want to disallow matching a string with a newline symbol at the end). 
  The `{3,25}` is a [**limiting quantifier**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) that allows matching `min` to `max` amount of characters conforming to the subpattern quantified. Note that a lookahead does not consume the text, i.e. the regex engine returns to the place where it starts matching the lookahead pattern with the `true` or `false` result, and if `true`, goes on matching the rest of the pattern.
- `[._-]?` - an optional single char, one of the defined chars in the character class (see explanation above)
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more (I wrote "1+") characters (the `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences) that are in the ranges defined in the character class.
- `(?:(?:[._-]|[ ][._-]?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` - is a [**non-capturing group**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap) used only for grouping subpatterns (to match them *consecutively*) that can match one or more (as the `*` stands after it) sequences of `(?:[._-]|[ ][._-]?)[a-zA-Z0-9]+`:
- `(?:[._-]|[ ][._-]?)` - either a `.`, `_`, or `-`, OR (due to the `|` [**alternation operator**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)) the space (I put the space into a character class `[ ]` because I used the `/x` VERBOSE modifier to introduce newline formatting and comments into the pattern, you may use a regular space if you do not use the `/x` modifier) followed with `.`, `_`, or `-`.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - 1 or more (due to `+`) alphanumerics.

Comment: why is there this \b ?

Comment: To require a word char at the start and end of the string. But I think you can remove them. They remained from my previous attempts. The current  pattern does not require these word boundaries.

Comment: well even though the comments are misleading and not very informative I analyzed the code and it is indeed the right answer.
thanks

Comment: Please let know what is misleading, I will update the answer.

Comment: ok here is what I think is good to explained and I learned on my own to understand this regex ( thank you apokryfos for your mentioning lookarounds and the link in your answer ) :
1. explain that (?=.{3,25}$) is a positive lookahead which allows for any from 3 to 25 length until the end with a link to how lookaheads works
2. dont use , to delimitate in comment line 3
3. explain why you choose to use a word boundary when there is apparently no use and a link to how \b works. the 4th line comment is very unclear and misleading "+ 1+ alphanumerics" for "upper and lower letters + digits"

Comment: 4. explain non capturing groups ?:

Comment: I will provide more links when my wife goes to bed. You already made me quarrel with her :)

Comment: Your wife was upset because your answer was not clear nor documented enough ? I would say she's a keeper :).

Comment: She thinks SO is evil even if I devote 15 minutes a day to answering comments on Saturday.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|[._-](?![ ._-]))(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]|[._-](?![ ._-])){1,23}[a-zA-Z0-9._-]$
```

The part `[._-](?![ ._-])` means "match `[._-]` if it's not followed by `[ ._-]`.

In general you can look into [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Oh, a usual "try-this" game started. No need guessing if the question is unclear. BTW, why overescape characters in the character class? `_` is not even a metacharacter. As for lookarounds: why are you checking for some text that should be missing *after* a string end with `(?![ \.\_\-])$`? It will always be true.

Comment: this was a correct answer to my question how i formulated it but I forget to say there couldn't be two consecutive spaces and no more than 2 special characters. So your answer was good and my question was bad. Sorry and thank you.